# selection.enter() is not a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart, updating

So, I made a bar chart visualization for a webapp, and it continuously updates over time as new data is entered in.

The webapp is [here](http://philosophyjourney.com).

As you can see, I am able to adjust the width of the bars as new data is entered in.  This was the code I used to do that:

```
function updateBarChart(currentInfo) {
    var bars = d3.select("#bar-chart")
                 .selectAll(".bar")
                 .data(currentInfo)
                 .transition()
                 .style("width", function(d) { return String(xScale(d.prob)) + "px"; });

    var h2s = d3.select("#bar-chart")
                .selectAll("h2")
                .data(currentInfo)
                .transition()
                .text(function(d) { return d.title; });

    var h1s = d3.select("#bar-chart")
                .selectAll("h1")
                .data(currentInfo)
                .transition()
                .text(function(d) { return String(Math.round(d.prob * 100)) + "%"; });

    bars.enter().append("div")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .transition()
        .style("width", function(d) { return String(xScale(d.prob)) + "px"; })

    bars.exit().remove()

    h2s.enter().append("h2")
       .transition()
       .text(function(d) { return d.title; })

    h2s.exit().remove()

    h1s.enter().append("h1")
       .transition()
       .text(function(d) { return String(Math.round(d.prob * 100)) + "%"; })

    h1s.exit().remove()

}
```

The input to the function is a list of dictionaries that have the form

```
{ title: 'title',
 prob: probability(float)
}
```

For some reason I keep getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: bars.enter is not a function".  I've looked over the code, which was inspired mostly by [this article on Medium.](https://medium.com/@c_behrens/enter-update-exit-6cafc6014c36#.260v5bukk)

Is there something wrong with my code here?  I'm pretty new to d3 so I'm not entirely sure if I'm missing something important.

Any help is appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**

If you check the chaining method, your "enter" selection right now is equivalent to this:

```
var bars = d3.select("#bar-chart")
    .selectAll(".bar")
    .data(currentInfo)
    .transition()
    .style("width", function(d) { return String(xScale(d.prob)) + "px"; })
    .enter().append("div")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .transition()
    .style("width", function(d) {
            return d + "px";
     })
```

Which will not work.

**Solution:**

Since the problem is that the `bars` variable should contain just the bound data, without the "update" part, this block:

```
 var bars = d3.select("#bar-chart")
     .selectAll(".bar")
     .data(currentInfo)
     .transition()
     .style("width", function(d) { return String(xScale(d.prob)) + "px"; });
```

Should be:

```
 var bars = d3.select("#bar-chart")
     .selectAll(".bar")
     .data(currentInfo);

 bars.transition()
     .style("width", function(d) { return String(xScale(d.prob)) + "px"; });
```

That way, your "enter" selection will be equivalent to this:

```
var bars = d3.select("#bar-chart")
     .selectAll(".bar")
     .data(currentInfo)
     .enter().append("div")
     .attr("class", "bar")
     .transition()
     .style("width", function(d) {
            return d + "px";
      })
```

Here is a demo using (parts of) your code:

```js
setInterval(function() {
    var data = d3.range(~~(Math.random() * 20)+1)
      .map(()=>~~(Math.random()*300));
    updateBarChart(data);
}, 2000);



function updateBarChart(currentInfo) {
    var bars = d3.select("body")
        .selectAll(".bar")
        .data(currentInfo);

    bars.transition()
        .style("width", function(d) {
            return d + "px";
        })
        .text(function(d) { 
            return d; 
        });

    bars.enter().append("div")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .transition()
        .style("width", function(d) {
            return d + "px";
        })
        .text(function(d) { 
            return d; 
        });

    bars.exit().remove();

}
```

```css
.bar {
  background-color: steelblue;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 1px;
  color: white;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```